# html radio button add to database

Tags: java, mysql, html, radio-button

I have a html radio button. When the user clicks the submit button, I want the value to be added to a database table.

there are the 4 radio buttons

```
o  a
o  b
o  c
o  d
```

--- I have used request.getParameter() and I have quoted q1. but when I check to see what is in the database table "null" is added. **How do I add the value in the database?**

here is my html radio buttons.

```
<FORM ACTION="Question2.jsp">
Q1. This is the section of code that gracefully responds to exceptions.<P>
    <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="q1" VALUE="a"/>a. Exception generator<BR>
    <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="q1" VALUE="b"/>b. Exception manipulator<BR>
    <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="q1" VALUE="c"/>c. Exception handler<BR>
    <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="q1" VALUE="d"/>d. Exception monitor<P>
    <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="submit"/>
</FORM>
```

... here I am trying to add the value in the table.

```
<%
String query = "INSERT INTO Quiz2 VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(query);
String answer = request.getParameter("q1");
pst.setString(1, answer);
pst.executeUpdate();
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `method="post"` in `<form>` tag.

```
<FORM ACTION="Question2.jsp" method="post">
```

And close the connection object after updating into database.

```
conn.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

If both of this (form and the jsp code) are in the same file (Question2.jsp) then, when you call it first time It will give you `NULL` values. Separate form and the code in two different file as `form.html` and `Question2.jsp`, this might prevent you from getting `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `answer` variable got the value correctly.

Comment: System.out.print(answer); but as it is a jsp nothing shows up.

Comment: `System.out.print(answer);` will write the value in server console. you can print with `out.print(answer);` in jsp scriptlet. or `${param.q1}` or, `${param[q1]}` (outside scriptlet), or `<%=request.getParameter("q1")%> `

Answer (score 0):

You prepared your statement, but you haven't executed it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing this multiple times ?

I am assuming that you have whole code in "`Question2.jsp`" and when first time `JSP` gets executed. It gets `NULL` value.

More, there is no need to cast in `(PreparedStatement)` as `Connection` returns the object of `PreparedStatement` only.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,

just do the things like

place your 1 html page in one page and Question2.jsp in another page

after that in question2.jsp place the code like this

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>


<%
Connection conn=null;
Statement stmt=null;
ResultSet rs=null;

String a=request.getParameter("q1");
System.out.println("Q1-->"+a);
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your database","your database username ","password");
System.out.println("connected");

stmt=conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("insert into first(username) values('"+a+"')");

%>
```

After this in your database place id (int) name(varchar(150)) your input will insert nicely

k.